# Fit each image to fill the entire cell in python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have the following code that inserts any image with the name `01.jpg` from multiple subfolders in folder named `MyFiles`, and insert those images to worksheet named `First` in the excel file named `MySample.xlsx`. The code works well but I need to auto fit the size of each image to fill the entire cell. The images are inserted into A1 - C1 - A3 - C3 - A5 - C5 and so on

```
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image

def insert_image_into_excel(excel_file, folder_path, worksheet_name, image_name):
    wb = load_workbook(excel_file)
    target_ws = wb[worksheet_name]
    current_row, current_col = 1, 1

    for subfolder_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
        subfolder_path = os.path.join(folder_path, subfolder_name)
        if os.path.isdir(subfolder_path):
            image_files = [f for f in os.listdir(subfolder_path) if f == image_name]
            if not image_files:
                continue

            for image_file in image_files:
                image_path = os.path.join(subfolder_path, image_file)
                img = Image(image_path)
                target_cell = target_ws.cell(row=current_row, column=current_col)
                target_ws.add_image(img, target_cell.coordinate)

                target_cell_width = target_ws.column_dimensions[target_cell.column_letter].width
                target_cell_height = target_ws.row_dimensions[current_row].height

                width_scale = target_cell_width / img.width
                height_scale = target_cell_height / img.height

                scale_factor = max(width_scale, height_scale)

                img.width = int(img.width * scale_factor)
                img.height = int(img.height * scale_factor)

                current_col = 3 if current_col == 1 else 1
                if current_col == 1:
                    current_row += 2
    wb.save(excel_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    insert_image_into_excel('MySample.xlsx', 'MyFiles', 'First', '01.jpg')
```